# content box responsive height

Tags: css, responsive-design

**Problem**

I am having an issue with getting the height of a responsive content box to fill the screen vertically.  everything including widths adjust fine to resizing in Dev Tools however when I adjust the content box height in the CSS code, I am only able to enter static heights in px (483 in code below).  When I try to set the height to 100%, my google map which is in the content box, disappears.  The map resizes fine as I manually adjust the content box `contenta` height so that seems to be functioning properly.  I have the meta tag as
`<meta content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0" charset="utf-8">`

Searching other questions hasn't resulted in any solutions.

**Question**

Is there coding that I am missing that allows the responsive content box to fill vertically?

[working test page](https://saltwx.com/responsive.html)

CSS

```
 body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 99%;
  height:100%;
  background-color: #52669c;
}

#map {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

#contenta {
  float: left;
  background: #0099ff;
  width: 95%;
  height: 483px;
}

#rightcolumn {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  width: 2%;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: It looks like your google map is inside of navbar? the height 100% will fill 100% of the height of its parent element. So unless all your parent elements height is 100%, it won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this template in your html for full width and full height

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://saltwx.com/css/responsive.css">
  <title>My website</title>
  <!--
  rest of your <head>
  -->
</head>
<body>
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <!--
  rest of your <body>
  -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

with this css

```
html, body, .page-wrapper {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.page-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```